# Why is the property called continuity of measure?

Tags: real-analysis

If $\left\{A_k \right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is an ascending collection of measurable sets then $m(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k) = \lim_{k\to\infty} m(A_k)$.

What does it have to do with continuity?

Comment: Think of sequential continuity.

Comment: It's similar to the way a continuous function carries convergent sequences to convergent sequences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intuitively, we can think of continuity as a property of a mapping where "limiting processes are preserved."  For instance, with a continuous function $f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$, we have for any convergent sequence $(x_n)$ that

$$
f(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x_n)
$$

This "continuity of measure" property is similar, since for an ascending collection of sets we can think of

$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n
$$ as the "limit"

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A_n
$$

So "continuity of measure" is really saying

$$
\mu(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}A_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_n)
$$ which is just like the continuity property for functions given above.

Comment: I mentioned "ascending" collection, yes.  I didn't want to go too deep into it.

Comment: Ah, missed that word. =)